# max_input_vars setting implication on other settings and performances

Tags: php, performance, apache2

I do not know if I use the wrong search terms or not but I do not find any clear answer to my question.

I work on an PHP application that generates the following message: "...PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 6000...".

According to my tests, I should increase the value for the parameter to 10000.

My question is the following: what are the implications to do that? As I am a newbie in questions of server configuration, I do not know if I must pay attention to others PHP settings parameters like "memory_limits" or something else.

I also see in some forum topics that has impacts on performances. Do I need to ask to the hosting platform to allocate more CPU or RAM?

Thanks

Comment: There will likely be no direct impact, but what does your script do to require that amount of input variables?

Comment: It has to treat big web forms.